# Change enum description during program execution

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

Not even sure if possible because can't find anything about that, i can find how to GET the current description written before program is executed but can't find a way to change (set/edit) the description of an enum when the program is already started, so if i have (just an example):

```
public enum MyColors {
    [Description("This is green, like a cactus")]
    Green,
    [Description("This is red, like blood")]
    Red,
    [Description("This is blue, you know like water")]
    Blue,
    [Description("This is black, like the eyes of an alien")]
    Black
}
```

How can i change the description during the program execution (while app is already started) or tell me "not possible" if it's not possible, thanks for your time.

Comment: You could add a dictionary (- observable if you need binding -) that has the enum values as key and the description as value, then use that instead. If it's for localization you could just associate a key string using an attribute and then look that up in you current localization context.

Comment: That's exatly what i'm was doing ;)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the value of the `Description` attribute, because attribute values are static and are baked into the compiled assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is defined in an attribute. The parameter (string) is compiled into the Intermediate Language IL hence they form part of your assembly. As a consequence you cannot change the description during run-time.

You will need to change the way you link enum values and descriptions if you require to change them during run-time. One way is to change to resource files.